# How to reference an entire column from one cell in a spreadsheet function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a way to accomplish the following using spreadsheet formulae: the output in cell D5 should be the array from cell B5 to the last populated cell (assume the range is contiguous). Thus if text were typed into cell B10, the output would automatically expand.

[image]

However, I want to avoid the volatile OFFSET and INDIRECT functions.

So I have this formula in cell D5:

```
=UPPER(B5:INDEX(B:B,ROW(B5)+COUNTA(B5:INDEX(B:B,ROWS(B:B),,1))-1))
```

but this is unsatisfactory as it references the B:B column.

*In effect I want a construction that returns me B:B given the cell B5* ie the equivalent of =`INDIRECT("C" & COLUMN(B5),"FALSE")`, but in a non-volatile format.

Any suggestions?

NB. I don't have the very latest Excel. I have LET, SEQUENCE, FILTER etc, but not LAMBDA and the functions that came with it (ie I can't do recursive LAMBDA calls).

Comment: `UPPER(FILTER(B:B, (B:B<>"")*(ROW()>=5)))`

Comment: @chrisneilsen That is certainly a neater way of rewriting my formula (if we replace `5` with `ROW(B5)`) but still doesn't get around the need to explicitly refer to B:B. If I drag and drop the range under B5 to somewhere else, I would like the formula to react. I fear I may have to swallow OFFSET, and use something like: `=LET(rng,OFFSET(B5,0,0,10000),FILTER(rng,LEN(rng)>0))` with a magic (and large) number of rows.

Comment: Re _If I drag and drop the range under B5 to somewhere else, I would like the formula to react._ How would you like it to react?

Comment: Designate your column B data as an Excel table, and then use a structured reference to it in your cell `D5` formula ?

Comment: @chrisneilsen Let's say I have a formula =B5. Once I have entered that, if I then insert or delete rows, or drag cell B5 to somewhere else, the formula will adjust to reference the new location of the cell. Eg if I drag cell B5 to a new position L10, the formula will now read =L10.

Comment: @SpectralInstance That's a great solution. Especially if I use Table Design to get rid of the header. If you'd care to put as a Answer, it would get a tick from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make column B data into a table

[image: screenshot of table illustrating structured referencing solution]

the content of cell `D5` can then be dragged to a different location, without the formula results changing.